# how to know about the font information in a psd file?

Tags: html, css, fonts, photoshop, psd

I have this psd and trying to convert it to html css.  But only thing I can't determine is what font they used in the psd?  How can i find out about the font information?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Click on the font tool (the T) and click the word or phrase you want, then click the A on the right side of the Photoshop screen and read in the little font window what it says.

This is not a question for this site, it should have been posted on superuser.com at least.

Answer (score 13):

To get the fonts information form a PSD file you can use online tools if you can't or won't use Photoshop (or if you prefer using Gimp, that rasterizes PSD fonts).

For example you can try out [this html5 PSD font online extractor](http://giovannimuzzolini.com/get-psd-fonts/) "Get PSD Fonts".

It's a PSD font information extractor based on [Melitingice Github project psd.js](http://meltingice.github.io/psd.js/) that does not require uploading files, working locally in your browser page

Comment: my license is expired, using Gimp to open my past PSDs wont let me know fonts information. But this javascript application does it for me. I can even save the webpage on my local from the browser and open it later. But using that website shouldn't be a problem as the file is not uploaded to a server, it is processed in your browser only

Answer (score 0):

Right-click a shape/text layer or layer group and choose Copy CSS from the context menu. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UppEO.png)